# Build android project in jenkins with oracle java

Tags: java, android, jenkins

I am getting this error when am trying to build an android with jenkins.
I do not think the error is jenkins related.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexProductionDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 137
```

the command that i am trying to execute (ProductionDebug is a flavour)

`./gradlew clean assembleProductionDebug --stacktrace`

**Edit 1**
So  I figured that this was an Out Of Memory Error from [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22849720/android-gradle-build-script-returns-error-137-in-predexdebug)

and the Jenkins Wiki also catalogs it [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/I'm+getting+OutOfMemoryError)

Now my question is:
Is it possible to run an android build with 1gb RAM?

**Edit 2**

I tried with with java 7u25 too,now the whole system becomes unresponsive and requires a restart from the AWS console.

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem a while ago, it turns out we have some errors in the RAM of the server we were useing. So I suggest you to run some tests on you server.

As for your question, 1GB RAM for the entire system or just for your project.

P.S. - Sorry for my ENG, it isn't that good, I hope this will help somehow.

Comment: entire server.,jenkins takes up about ~400 Mb,so I guess the rest would be for the build.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to to make this work. providing a 512 mb swap memory managed to assemble the app.Although it takes about 8~9 minutes.

I wont accept this answer hoping that there is a better solution.